# bash: running a sequence of commands in a subshell with fail-on-error

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a sequence of commands I want to run in such a way that when any command fails, the rest of the commands should no longer be executed. Let's assume the sequence of commands is

```bash
echo foo
false
echo bar
```

(i.e., I want `foo` to be echoed but not `bar`).

This should happen within a script that is run with `set -e`, which I *don't* want to fail in its entirety if the above sequence of commands fails. My initial idea was to use a subshell

```bash
( echo foo ; false ; echo bar ; ) || true
```

but that doesn't work, both `foo` and `bar` are printed, because per the POSIX spec, `set -e` loses its effect on the left-hand side of `||`, same as within an `if` condition (I think this portion of the spec is conceptually flawed because it breaks abstraction, but oh well, no changing the POSIX specs now). An explicit `set -e` within the parentheses cannot fix this either.

I also cannot do `set +e ... set -e` around this portion, because instead of `|| true` I would want to run some alternative command that might fail and should cause the script to fail. (Besides that, restoring state via explicit `set` commands is ugly.)

So it would seem I'm left with either `set +e` + explicit checking of `$?` afterwards, or running the sequence of commands as a separate script (either in a separate file, or via `bash <<EOF ...`), with the downside of not being able to access (array) variables easily.

Frankly, this seems like a fairly regular use case that the implicit and forced `+e` within left-hand sides within expressions used as conditions makes disproportionately and surprisingly hard. Is there any easy option I'm missing?

Comment: Running the commands in a new shell instance would work, but I'm assuming you're after something nicer looking? `sh -ec 'echo foo ; false ; echo bar' || true`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a series of commands up to the first failure:

```
$ command1 && command2 && command3 && command4
```

The `&&` token will execute the command on the right if and only if the command on the left returns a zero exit code.